# Replace one line in a text file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, file-io

I have a text file that is used by another application as a configuration file. I have read in each line of the file into a String array:

```
string[] arrLine = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
```

which works exactly how i need it to.

Now, all i need to do is replace the entire line of arrLine[x] with a string, overwriting what is there on that line and that line only. I have wrote code to know the exact line i need to replace, i just need to know how to replace it.

I am thinking of arrLine[x].Replace(oldString, newString) - if this works, how would i actually commit the change to the text file? Do i somehow need to rewrite the whole file? Im thinking that would be a little on the inefficient side when only one line needs rewriting?

Comment: Just overwrite the string that is there with an assignment. No need for replace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to just assign that element:

```
arrLine[yourLineNumber] = "Foo";
```

> how would i actually commit the change to the text file?

Once you've done this, you can use `File.WriteAllLines(pathToFile, arrLine);` to write the data back to the original file.

Comment: This does not in fact answer the critical question, which I understand to be "Is it necessary to re-write the entire file, or is there a way to replace only the single line that was changed?" Something like "sed for C#" is what is really wanted here. sed itself can be called from a mono c# program in Linux with Stdlib.system("sed -i s?etc blah blah"), but this can get messy.

Comment: Ok so i just read a 1.5gb PLY point cloud to change line 3. It used 8GB of ram. It would make sense have File.WriteSingeLine();

Comment: @comprehensible For huge files - It's typically better to stream it and copy/write to a separate file, then move over the original.